# Loading CSS elements into Rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a welcome folder in a Rails application to house the `index.html.erb` file where the root directs it to, and I have all the HTML and CSS done, yet when I try to link it to the HTML with regular tags, it does not seems to work.

How to load my CSS in the Rails HTML file? 
Does the CSS file have to be in a specific folder in the assets folder?

here is application.rb code:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Indiecritic
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

where do i put the code to include the other css assets?

Comment: add your css connecting code, and firstly check your pathes

Comment: what do you mean by connecting code, and thanks for the answer @aleshaoleg

Comment: I mean code where you link your css like in first answer. Sorry:)

Comment: ok i see.  this weird reoccurring problem happens now, where every time i put in a path that should work, it links the wrong files, and doesn't read some correctly.  it is so weird i cant figure out why it has any reason to do this... for example, i will link a css file that would change some colors, and there would be two of these files, both having different color properties. i will link to one and get the other color, very annoying. it also messes with the html which i cant figure out either. @aleshaoleg

Comment: just take me a couple minutes to answer another question, and I will start my rails project to check it.

Comment: thank you very much take all the time you need @aleshaoleg

Comment: So, I created controller `welcome` with ` rails generate controller welcome index` that added to me index to `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` and in `app/assets/stylesheet/application.css` and to my `h1` in `index.html.erb` I applied `color: red`. Everything works. What I do not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stylesheets go in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

You include them thusly (for `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

If you are precompiling assets other than `application.css`, make sure to include it in the list of assets to precompile (in your `config/application.rb`):

```
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( something_else.css )
```

Then you include them thusly (for `app/assets/stylesheets/something_else.css`):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :something_else %>
```

### EDIT

OR...
You can add your `somehting_else.css` to the `application.css` manifest by adding this near the top of the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file:

```
*= require somehting_else
```

You should read up on [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Here are a couple Railscasts related to the Asset Pipeline:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/341-asset-pipeline-in-production

Comment: can you check my edits to the question with the informtion you just gave me in mind please

Comment: Anywhere in your `config/application.rb` should be fine (as long as you are using a recent version of Rails like `>=4.1.2`). I prefer to have as assets initializer in `config/initializers/assets.rb` which includes all my assets config directives.